# HIbernate - GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, connection-pooling

We have deployed a Java application in Tomcat7. Normally 40- 80 users use our application regularly. However our application going down twice in a week.

I am very new to Hibernate configuration. I suspect that our application is not responding due to connection leak issue. However I am not sure. I need some experts suggestion to move forward to save my application.

Herewith I have attached my error logs as well as hibernate configuration. I see lot of posts related to my questions. However I have not found the answers related to my question. So, please do not ignore this question. Kindly help me on this.

Info: I have found one module is establishing the connection much more whenever we access it. I have fixed it by setting it Connection Release Mode to **After Transaction** . Please correct me if I am wrong.

Hibernate - 3.1.0
Spring - 3.6.10
c3p0 - 0.9.1.2
Java - 1.7

This is my Catalina.out error log:

```
 *Cannot open connection
    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
        at com.turborep.turbotracker.job.service.JobServiceImpl.getCuSOID(JobServiceImpl.java:11409)
        at com.turborep.turbotracker.job.controller.SalesOrderController.getCuSOID(SalesOrderController.java:313)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2680.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
        at com.turborep.turbotracker.RewriteFilter.forwardRequest(RewriteFilter.java:84)
        at com.turborep.turbotracker.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:62)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:531)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
        ... 53 more
    Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1315)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
        ... 56 more*
```

My **hibernate-context.xml** as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            ">

    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />

    <bean id="userServiceDao" class="xxx.system.service.SysServiceImpl" >
    </bean>

    <bean id="sysServiceDao" class="xx.user.service.UserServiceImpl" >
    </bean>


    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

    <!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
    <!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html -->                           
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html -->
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
                 p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
                 p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
                 p:packagesToScan="xxx"/>




    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
                destroy-method="close"
                p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
                p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
                p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
                p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
                p:acquireIncrement="5"
                p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
                p:maxPoolSize="2500"
                p:maxStatements="5000"
                p:minPoolSize="5" 
                p:testConnectionOnCheckout="true"
                p:maxConnectionAge="300"

                 />

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
                p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

</beans>
```

My **hibernate-cfg.xml** as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- We're using MySQL database so the dialect needs to MySQL as well-->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <!-- Enable this to see the SQL statements in the logs-->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <!-- This will drop our existing database and re-create a new one.
            Existing data will be deleted! -->
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.provider">cglib</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>

    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
<!--  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.factory_class">net.bull.javamelody.HibernateBatcherFactory</property>   -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction </property> 
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Have you used any profiler to see when a connection opens and closed?

Comment: Yes Naveen. I am using Javamelody monitoring in my application.